# My question is related to zina

Tags: halal-haram, sin, women, sex, zina

I had bad thoughts about my aunt for a long time so I decided to do something with her.she has been married for 10 years and has 2 childrens. Next time I meet her I talked  with her give me a handjob and a blowjob.she was very hesitant but she gave me a blowjob and handjob and we both were naked.now I feel guilty and I have said sorry to her.So would this be considered as zina ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the punishment for unlawful Non-penetrative sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77490/what-is-the-punishment-for-unlawful-non-penetrative-sex)

Answer (score 1):

Bismillahirrahmanirrahim, Assalamualaikum, I will explain it one by one. And may you read this with an open heart as most people including myself feels really bad to read through things talking about sins we made.

This obviously is zina, just by apologizing it to her doesn't mean the sin is being lifted already. You haven't apologized and repent to Allah.

Here is the explanation from the beginning to the end;

1. She is your aunt, so she is your mahram which makes it haram
2. It's haram and is a zina because you guys are not married (but since you guys both are mahram anyway, you still can't marry each other which still makes it a zina)
3. Even awrah between our mahram and family is from navel to knee which is haram to see and look at, and even touching someone's awrah is a sin as what I have heard Ustadz said unless if it is your wife/husband, let alone this which actually make you pleasure and more.
4. Even having bad thoughts about someone is considered as zina, in what way makes you think if this is zina or not when it clearly is?
5. There is this surah Al Isra verses 32 that says “Do not go near adultery (zina). It is truly a shameful deed and an evil way.” this clearly says “do not go near” it didn't say “don't” only, which means since you already did it, it is zina.
6. Also there's this surah Al Mukminun verses 5-7 saying “And they who guard their private parts, Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will not be blamed But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the transgressors” read this carefully and understand what sin you just made.
7. The only way is to repent from the zina & sin you made, you feeling guilty is a sign that you still have Iman, which is not too late to repent to Allah by giving up on the sin , regretting it, promise and avoid to not do it again.

Wallahua'lam. May Allah forgive all of our sins InshaAllah.

Comment: I like the answer. The OP can repent honestly for forgiveness