# Is oral sex major zina?

Tags: sex, zina

I know the major zina is penetration into the women’s private part. It’s also clear that getting pleasure before marriage by any means is not allowed. In my case if I was to was to receive oral pleasure, would it be considered minor or major zina?
At the same time is getting a handjob major or minor zina. Because it counts just as touching?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the punishment for unlawful Non-penetrative sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77490/what-is-the-punishment-for-unlawful-non-penetrative-sex)

Answer (score 0):

Well brother/sister it depends are you having that with your wife that everyone knows you married and you both have a contract of marriage and you are married and you plan to stay together forever then sure it is okay to do what you want with her as long as she consents. But if this is not a marriage then it is best not to do that with her or touch her at all and do not stay in a place alone with her make sure there is someone from both sides avaliable and sitting with you. And do not date just marry but you are allowed to get to know the person before marriage (BUT NOT DATE THEM) i hope this answers your question

Oral is just as penertration same sin same everything