# Does Rubbing a boy private part between woman’s buttocks before menstuation at age 14 considered zina or major sin?

Tags: sin, sex, forgiveness

Does it comes in zina?
What if somebody is not aware of it and get to know about it at age 14

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the punishment for unlawful Non-penetrative sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77490/what-is-the-punishment-for-unlawful-non-penetrative-sex)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are asking this when both are in clothed state. It is not a major sin. Also it might sometime happen accidently in very crowded places.

> Those who avoid the major sins and immoralities, only [committing]
> slight ones. Indeed, your Lord is vast in forgiveness. He was most
> knowing of you when He produced you from the earth and when you were
> fetuses in the wombs of your mothers. So do not claim yourselves to be
> pure; He is most knowing of who fears Him. [Quran 53:32](https://quran.com/en/an-najm/32)

We should do our best to avoid doing haram things. But we are humans and may do some haram things and the remedy for this is to do good deeds to compensate for the haram things.

> A man kissed a woman and then came to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and told
> him of that, so this Divine Inspiration was revealed to the Prophet
> (ﷺ) 'And offer Prayers perfectly at the two ends of the day, and in
> some hours of the night; (i.e. (five) compulsory prayers). Verily, the
> good deeds remove the evil deeds (small sins) That is a reminder for
> the mindful.' (11.114) The man said, Is this instruction for me only?'
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "It is for all those of my followers who
> encounter a similar situation." https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4687

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question but I will answer it as if you said is having s@x with a woman before menstruation. Well brother I would recommend when you are older to get married to avoid doing sin and never let your desires take you away from Allah(swt)

To repent you must apologize sincerely to allah and say that you will not do this again (promise) and stop doing the action. And if you fall in sin again repent again .Allah(swt) is all knowing most forgiving most merciful

You cannot have s@x with a non mehram such as your cousin, classmate etc... but for example your mother is a mehram but you cannot do that with her same with your grandmother etc... and dad etc... you cannot do that with other boys too only your wife that you married and the conditions that I know of are having a contract, it cannot be a pleasure marriage, and people must know you are married (family,friends etc) and it is both zina and a major sin BUT DO NOT WORRY ALLAH WILL INSHALLAH ACCEPT YOUR REPENTANCE HE ACCEPTS ALL REPENTANCE EVEN IF YOU SINNED YOUR ENTIRE LIFE.Have a good day brother may allah help you inshallah and jazakallah for reading also lower your gaze it prevents you from sinning