# Sharamggah ki taraf dekhna Zina hai

Tags: hanafi

Mai larka houn or Mai dusre ki sharamgah ko dekhta houn liekn us ne kapde bhi pehne hote haio or ma fiq hanafi se houn Kiya halal hai ya Haram ?or yeh Zina hai

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the punishment for unlawful Non-penetrative sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77490/what-is-the-punishment-for-unlawful-non-penetrative-sex)